# Multimodule logging with Python and Celery

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

I have implemented a Celery task which makes use of some external libraries.

Let's say the task code is something like this:

```
# mypackage.tasks
import logging
from extpackage1 import module1
from extpackage2 import module2

from celery import Celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

celery = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://user:pass@host/vhname')

logger = get_task_logger(__name__)

@celery.task
def my_task(my_job_id):
    logger.info('My task executed with my_job_id=%s' % my_job_id)
    module1.func1()
    module2.func2()
```

while the 2 modules I import are basically:

```
# extpackage1.module1
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    

def func1():
    # let's do something here ...
    logger.info('Logging inside module1')
```

and:

```
# extpackage2.module2
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)    

def func2():
    # let's do something here ...
    logger.info('Logging inside module2')
```

I would like to obtain a log file which include the correct value of `my_job_id` in each line, depending on the task which is executed.

It would be something such as:

```
[1][...other info..] My task executed with my_job_id=1
[1][...other info..] Logging inside module1
[1][...other info..] Logging inside module2
[2][...other info..] My task executed with my_job_id=2
[2][...other info..] Logging inside module1
[2][...other info..] Logging inside module2
```

I could easily include the value of `my_job_id` into the task logger, correctly obtaining the lines I log from inside the task function (like `[1][...other info..] My task executed with my_job_id=1` and `[2][...other info..] My task executed with my_job_id=2`).

But what about the external libraries? Is there an elegant way to 'wrap' the log produced by the external script and format it according to my requirements?